# Manim code doesn't work gives error "Mobject.getattr.<locals>.getter() got an unexpected keyword argument "x_range"

Tags: python, keyword, getattr, manim

I repeat the video on tutorials on creating a graph in manim.  I do everything the same as in the video, but I get an error, I attach the code below and the error too.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7Bxo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plDxB.png)

I tried to remove the code on line 9, and everything works out for me, but there is no parabola.  I had a similar problem and with the height argument I thought the problem was in the library, I reinstalled everything, it didn’t help and now I think that I’m doing something wrong.  Where could I be wrong?  I'm not strong in Python, only now I'm learning a beginner.  Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely following an outdated tutorial: the `get_graph` method has been renamed to `plot` quite a while ago. Change your line

```py
plane.get_graph(lambda x: x**2, ...)
```

to

```py
plane.plot(lambda x: x**2, ...)
```

and the code should compile.

In general: please don't share your code via screenshots here, just copy/paste it within a code block.

Comment: Thanks, it helped.  Now the question is why didn't it work here as well?  "grid = Tex(r"\pi").get_grid(10, 10, height=4)
         self.add(grid)" is complaining about height here